# Declaration of variables

Tags: jquery

I have some code that I am reviewing through jsHint and jsLint. They both show up on the report as either an error or undeclared variable.

**My code:**

```
    $("#btn_details").button().click(function() {
```

**jsLint reports back:** Error

```
    '$' was used before it was defined.
        $("#btn_details").button().click(function() {
```

**jsHint reports back:** Undeclared variable

```
    $
```

My code works in testing, but I like to not have any unnecessary errors if I can help it. Or maybe this is a really bad nasty no no. But is it correct, or am I suppose to fix it somehow?

Comment: `$` here refers to the `jQuery` object. You probably didn't load the library before using it.

Comment: And do you submit to JSLint the whole code, including jQuery's one ?

Comment: `$` is only included as a global variable when the jQuery library is loaded.  jsLint/jsHint don't auto-include `$` unless you tell them to.  Add `/*global $ */` to the top of your script.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for the `/* global $ */` that makes sense. Can you put that in the answer and I'll accept that. Btw. Why all the negative votes? I'm new to this language and it's a legitimate learning experience for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the comment `/*global $ */` to the top of your script.  This will tell jsLint/jsHint to expect `$` to be a pre-defined global.

This global is normally set by including jQuery in your page.